# Appropriate Future Handling in Akka Actors Typed

Tags: scala, akka, akka-typed

What is the proper way to handle Futures from inside an Akka (typed) Actor?

For example, assume there is an Actor `OrderActor` that receives Commands to place orders... which it does by making an http call to an external service. Since these are http calls to an external service, `Future`s are involved. So, what is the right way to handle that `Future` from within the Actor.

I read something about the pipeTo pattern. Is that what needs to happen here or something else?

```
class OrderActor(context: ActorContext[OrderCommand], orderFacade: OrderFacade)
    extends AbstractBehavior[OrderCommand](context) {

  context.log.info("Order Actor started")

  override def onMessage(msg: OrderCommand): Behavior[OrderCommand] = {

    msg match {

      case PlaceOrder(
            referenceId: OrderReferenceId,
            ticker: Ticker,
            quantity: Int,
            replyTo: ActorRef[OrderResult]
          ) =>
        orderFacade
          .placeOrder(ticker, quantity) //this returns a Future
          .map(res => {

            //transform result
            //book keeping / notification (affects state)
            replyTo ! transformed

            //Can/Should we map like  this? I tried adding a log statement in here, but I never see it... and the replyTo doesnt seem to get the message. 

          })

        this
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's generally best to avoid doing `Future` transformations (`map`, `flatMap`, `foreach`, etc.) inside an actor.  There's a distinct risk that some mutable state within the actor isn't what you expect it to be when the transformation runs.  In Akka Classic, perhaps the most pernicious form of this would result in sending a reply to the wrong actor.

Akka Typed (especially in the functional API) reduces a lot of the mutable state which could cause trouble, but it's still generally a good idea to pipe the `Future` as a message to the actor.

So if `orderFacade.placeOrder` results in a `Future[OrderResponse]`, you might add subclasses of `OrderCommand` like this

```scala
// also include fields from the PlaceOrder which will be useful
case class OrderResponseIs(resp: OrderResponse, replyTo: ActorRef[OrderResult]) extends OrderCommand
// TODO include fields
case class OrderFailed() extends OrderCommand
```

And then pipe the `Future` to yourself with:

```scala
import scala.util.{ Failure, Success }

context.pipeToSelf(orderFacade.placeOrder) {
  case Success(resp) => OrderResponseIs(resp, replyTo)
  case Failure(_) => OrderFailed()
}
```

You then have to handle those messages:

```scala
case OrderResponseIs(resp, replyTo) =>
  // transform resp
  val transformed = ???

  replyTo ! transformed

  this

case OrderFailed() =>
  context.log.warning("Stuff is broken")

  this
```

There's not actually much overhead in doing this versus `map` and friends (both will typically involve scheduling a task for asynchronous execution on the dispatcher).